# Invalid ViewState / Invalid character in a Base-64 string

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I've read multiple similar posts on this. For example:

- [Invalid character in a base-64 string - ViewState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731010/invalid-character-in-a-base-64-string-viewstate)
- [Invalid character in a Base-64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054583/invalid-character-in-a-base-64-string)

But none provided the solution for me. I have an idea what is going wrong, and I'll try to walk through my code.

This only happens to a handful of users a day, and all of them use IE. Firefox works as it should.

I have one aspx page which holds a registration form for my webshop. When the user clicks "Proceed," I do a postback which validates data. If everything is valid, I run this code:

```
public void Proceed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (IsValid)
   {
      SaveCustomerInfo();
      ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
          this, this.GetType(),
          "RedirectPaymentGateway",
          "RedirectPaymentGateway('" + paymentData + "');", true);
   }
}
```

This script redirects the user to the payment gateway like this:

```
function RedirectPaymentGateway(paymentData) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        try {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = paymentData;                
            var formDataObj = jQuery.parseJSON(div.firstChild.nodeValue);

            var form = "<form>FORM CONSTRUCTION</form>";

            $('#pnlPaymentGateway').html(form);
            $('#pnlPaymentGateway').submit();
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }            
    });
}
```

(`paymentData` is a JSON serialization of a .net object.)

I'm guessing this code breaks something related to the viewstate, but I can't figure out how or why. Any suggestions?

Comment: Multiple forms on a page aren't valid in `ASP.NET`

Comment: I know that, but this second form is rendered outside the asp.net form tag.

Comment: So when the server receives the content of that form, the ViewState isn't being returned, hence the error.

Comment: But what I cant understand is that the server does not get the content of that form, the form is rendered and submitted through jQuery after the postback. And why does this work for almost every user except a few unlucky ones?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue with a user. It only happens with IE, but not with all users. Firefox and Chrome work fine.

To fix the issue, open IE and do the following:

1. Click on Tools. (You may need to enable the menu bar first by right clicking the top bar.)
2. Click on Internet Options.
3. Click the Advanced tab.
4. Click Reset.
5. Check the box to delete personal settings.
6. Confirm until back to IE.
7. Restart the browser.

The problem will be fixed.